# How the inner product of a function with itself is always greater than or equal to zero?

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces

The inner product of two functions over an interval $[a, b]$ is defined as:
$$\langle f|g \rangle = \int_a^b f(x)^* g(x) dx$$

From it we get:
$$\langle f|f \rangle = \int_a^b |f(x)|^2 dx$$

I have studied that $\langle f|f \rangle \geq 0$. But when I think about it something seems fishy because if we interchange the limits of the interval:
$$\int_b^a |f(x)|^2 dx = -\int_a^b |f(x)|^2 dx$$
Suggesting $\langle f|f \rangle$ can be $\leq 0$ as well, just the integration should be from a higher value of $x$ to a lower value of $x$.

Can you help in understanding this?

Comment: $\int_a^{b}|f(x)|^{2} \geq 0$ if $a<b$. Not true for $a >b$. In the definition of inner product we always take $a<b$.

Comment: @Kavi thank you for your response. I had always thought that this was the only possibility but decided to confirm it from an academic community.